# How to get meta value by meta id

Tags: wordpress

Example, I have a post's `meta_key` is 'name', `meta_value` is 'Jason',
and this `meta_id` in MySQL is 128

How can I get this meta_value by meta_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://wpseek.com/blog/2010/how-to-get-the-meta-id-by-meta-key/80/) which might help you.

It describes *How to get the Meta ID by Meta Key*, so it is not exactly what you need but quite similar. Maybe all that is required is to modify that query a little.

Comment: Thanks, I'm coding a function

function get_meta_value_by_meta_id( $meta_id ) {

 global $wpdb;

 $meta_value = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_id = %s", $meta_id) );

 return $meta_value;
}

Comment: Cool. If this answer helped solve your problem, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the big checkbox on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use WordPress's built-in function, [`get_metadata_by_mid()`](http://wpseek.com/get_metadata_by_mid/).

So in your case:

```
$value = get_metadata_by_mid( 'post', 128 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_metadata_by_mid( $meta_type, $meta_key )` will work for most situations. It returns an object with all the postmeta data.

```
$jason = get_metadata_by_mid( 'post', 128 );
echo 'Meta Value = ' . $jason->meta_value;
echo 'Post ID = ' . $jason->post_id;

// Results
Meta Value = Jason
Post ID = 123
```

If you need to do something a bit more custom such as get stock status of product using the meta id. You can use this.

```
global $wpdb;

$meta_id = 128;
$postmeta_post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_id = %d", $meta_id) );

$stock_status = get_post_meta( $postmeta_post_id, '_stock_status', single );

echo 'Product status: ' . $stock_status;

//results
Product status: outofstock
```